# Statistics Question on Transforming and Combining Random Variables

Tags: integration, statistics

The Question: Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables. Given their marginal pdf's indicated below, find the C.D.F. of $\frac{Y}{X}$.

$f_{X}(x) = 1$, $0 \leq x \leq 1$. $f_{Y} (y) = 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1$.

The Attempt:

Since we are trying to find the C.D.F., by definition, $F_{w} (w) = P( \frac{Y}{X} \leq w)$. This means that $F_{w} (w) = P(Y \leq wx)$. Since $0\leq y \leq 1$, this implies that $w \leq \frac{1}{x}$. I also attempted to look at the cases when $0 \leq w \leq 1$ and when $w > 1$. However, I am trying to figure out how to compute the CDF of marginal density functions.

Do you have any hints or ideas on how to work on this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The problem is solved at the beginning of this [video lecture](https://youtu.be/l4NoMKEHQwM?t=1m33s).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your initial region $\Omega$ is the box $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$. Your event $Y/X \leq w$ introduces the constraint $Y = wX$ (for each fixed $w$), which is a line passing through the origin.

Define a region $A$ which is the part of $\Omega$ below the line $Y = wX$, and find the area of the region, e.g. by double integral over it (it should depend on $w$ but not on $x,y$). This area will be exactly $\mathbb{P}[Y \le Xw]$, since the area of $\Omega$ is exactly 1.